# Java Return an Optional<String> from findFirst()

Tags: java, return, option-type

I am working with Optional now, and I have to return a String from a findFirst() method. I know that findFirst returns an Optional but I would like to return an `Optional<String>` as in in the method signature.

```
@Override
    public Optional<String> findBetweenMinAgeAndMaxAge(int kidAge, String id) {
        String query = buildFindRoomByKidAge();
        JsonObject params = JsonObject.create()
                .put(JAVA_TYPE_PARAM, ShipRoom.class.getName())
                .put(ID_PARAM, id)
                .put(KID_AGE_PARAM, kidAge);

        N1qlQuery queryWithParameter = N1qlQuery.parameterized(query, params);

        return template.findByN1QLProjection(queryWithParameter, Room.class)
                .stream()
                .findFirst();
    }
```

Is there any sophisticated way to achieve this?

I made the next:

```
@Override
    public Optional<String> findBetweenMinAgeAndMaxAge(int kidAge, String id) {
        String query = buildFindRoomByKidAge();
        JsonObject params = JsonObject.create()
                .put(JAVA_TYPE_PARAM, ShipRoom.class.getName())
                .put(ID_PARAM, id)
                .put(KID_AGE_PARAM, kidAge);

        N1qlQuery queryWithParameter = N1qlQuery.parameterized(query, params);

        return Optional.ofNullable(template.findByN1QLProjection(queryWithParameter, Room.class)
                .stream()
                .findFirst().get().getId());
    }
```

But I think there should be a better solution. Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Optional.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) :

```
 return template.findByN1QLProjection(queryWithParameter, Room.class)
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
                .map(Room::getId)
```

`map()` accepts a function which the result is returned if a value is present in the optional.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have an `Optional<Room>` as a result you can map it further use [`Optional#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) as:

```
return template.findByN1QLProjection(queryWithParameter, Room.class)
            .stream()
            .findFirst()
            .map(room -> room.getId());
```

Do note, as per your second revision, the `map` takes care of the `id` being `null` on its own and returns `Optional.empty` for such values. From the javadoc:

> If the mapping function returns a null result then this method returns
>   an empty Optional.